# Why does the BFG look so old compared to the rest of the giants?

Tags: roald-dahl

I went to see the movie adaption of *The BFG* by Roald Dahl. One thing I noticed was that the Big Friendly Giant (or, as they called him in the dubbed version, the *EEG*,) looked like an old man. All of the rest of the giants were big, strong, bald, and young-looking. Not our BFG - he has gray hair, and just looks like an old man.

**Why does the BFG look so old in comparison to the other giants?**

Comment: Welcome back! :-)

Comment: Maybe eating humans helps fight wrinkles?

Comment: @RogueJedi alternatively the daily horror of snozzcumbers has aged him...

Answer (score 5):

The most obvious reason for him to *look older* is simply because he *is older*. Bearing in mind that the BFG has evidently seen other giants appearing and disappearing, one would assume that something (perhaps his sense of purpose, or his exclusive diet of healthy, but disgusting snozzcumbers) has prevented him from suffering the same fate as his contemporaries.

> 'Giants isn't born,' the BFG answered. 'Giants appears and that's all there is to it. They simply appears, the same way as the sun and the stars.'   
>   **'And when did you appear?'** Sophie asked. 
>   **'Now how on earth could I be knowing a thing like that?' said the BFG. 'It was so long ago I couldn't count.'** 
>   'You mean you don't even know how old you are?' 
>   'No giant is knowing that,' the BFG said. 'All I is knowing about myself is that I is very old, very very old and crumply. Perhaps as old as the earth.' 
>   'What happens when a giant dies?' Sophie asked. 
>   **'Giants is never dying,' the BFG answered. 'Sometimes and quite suddenly, a giant is disappearing and nobody is ever knowing where he goes to. But mostly us giants is simply going on and on like whiffsy time-twiddlers.'**
>
> <sub><sup>[The BFG - Roald Dahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_BFG)</sup></sub>

The implication seems to be that other giants come and go (eventually) but the BFG simply *endures.*

Comment: And who's to say that the other giants aren't the same age?

Comment: @Mithrandir - The impression I got was that he's outlived his contemporaries. He's seen multiple giants disappear in his lifetime.

Comment: On the other hand, the line "No giant is knowing that," seems more likely to mean "No giant is knowing [how old they are]" (although "No giant is knowing  [how old the BFG is]" could also work). If the BFG was older than the other giants, they could find out how old they were by asking him. If they cared, and assuming the BFG had some way of tracking ther passage of time. Purely playing devil's advocate here though; I quite like your idea. He's clearly different to the others in some fairly major way, given his height, appearance and behaviour.